# How to add a <br/> into source code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i got this code:

```
<h1>JavaScript File API demo</h1>
<div id="container">
<label>Upload files to local repository:</label><input type="file" accept=".js" id="uploaded" multiple="multiple"/>
<div id="fileInfo" ></div>

</div>
<p></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(!(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)){
    $('#fileContent, input, button, #examples').fadeOut("fast");
    $('<p>Oh no, you need a browser that supports File API. How about <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google/a>?</p>').appendTo('#container');
  } else {
          $("#uploaded").change(function (e) {
                var files = e.target.files; // FileList object
                // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
                var output = [];
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                  output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), 
                            '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                            '</li>');
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function(e) {
                      $("#fileInfo").append("<li> Data from file: " + e.target.result + "</li>");
                  };
                  reader.readAsText(f);
                }
                $("#fileInfo").append('<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>' );
          });
  }
});
```

Now, this is the code, for me to upload a javascript (.js) file to my html page...and to read the code from the file into the text field

Now i get all the code i need, and all, but i dont get it like i wrote it...i mean, there are no tabs, no new lines, or something...(but my javascript code has it all)...so for now, i want just to add the new line to my text box...eventually the tab too....but first the new line...

i already tried to add the 
 to my code in this line

```
 $("#fileInfo").append('<ul>' + output.join('') <!--I added it here--> + '</ul>'  <!--I added it here--> );
```

ofc with the "", and with the ''...

but it didnt work...
mby u know a better way, it does not have to be the br tag...

can u help me?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `replace()` method to replace all newlines with `<br>`, like so:

```
$("#fileInfo").append("<li> Data from file: " + e.target.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>").replace(/[ ]/g,"&nbsp;" ) + "</li>");
```

Comment: Sure! Look at my updated code. `replace()` method replaces all occurrences of given expression with given replacement. If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

Comment: nope, the second part does not work for me...replace(/[ ]/g,"&nbsp;" )

Comment: i tried /\t/ but it didnt work...mby there is something esle to try?